# I want to buy 1 apple. How to calculate the total amount I need to buy if I return 0.2% of it back?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, percentages

I need to receive 1 apple. When I buy 1 apple I always return 0.2% of apples back.

I.e. if I buy 1 apple then I receive 0.998 of apple.
If I buy 1.002 I receive 0.999996 of apple
If I buy 1.002004008016032064128256... then I receive 1 apple.

How to calculate the amount of apples I need to buy so that when I return 0.2% of it I would have 1 apple? Which formula I need to use?

Comment: You should go to a grocer who does not charge interests over the interests.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean with "When I buy 1 apple I need to pay 0.2% of apple."? Is that some kind of interest or additional fee?

Comment: I need to return 0.2% of anything I receive. The question is how much of apple I need to buy to get 1 apple after I returned 0.2% of it. What is the formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say, that you buy $x$ units of something (e.g. apples).

You have to return $0.2\%$ of what you've bought, so after that you have $(1-0.002)x$ units of something.

Now you want, that after returning $0.2\%$ you would have $n$ apples.

Thus:
$$(1-0.002)x=n$$

You just need to solve this equation for $x$:
$$x=\frac{n}{.998}$$

Comment: Please add some details  on how to derive this equation from the given .

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I would also add a solved equation. I.e. x = n / 0.998